# Laravel working with arrays and looping through associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops

Consider I have the following array (passed to view from my controller):

```
'first' => [

    '1' => [
        'title' => 'First Div',
        'fields' => [
            'name', 'select'
        ],
    ],

     'divider',

    '2' => [
        'title' => 'Second Div',
        'fields' => [
            'address'
        ],
    ],
```

Looks like this in the browser when I dump:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'First Div' (length=9)
      'fields' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'name' (length=4)
          1 => string 'select' (length=6)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'title' => string 'Second Div' (length=10)
      'fields' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'address' (length=7)
```

What I am trying to do is the following. I want to loop through all arrays, then display a div with a `title`, and within that div, loop through all the `fields` for each array.

For now I am focussing on just the looping through the array and displaying the right data, so without any divs yet. So something like this:

```
@foreach($first as $key => $value)

    // Unsure what to do here

@endforeach
```

I've tried a lot of things (just playing around trying to dump or echo out data), and I cannot even figure out how to display the `title`, let alone loop through all the `fields` values.

Either way, my ultimate goal is to create the following, dynamic view, based on what is passed from the controller:

[image: Example]

Comment: Well `$value` will also be an array, so add another foreach loop to process that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To echo out a value in blade you can wrap your variable in `{{ }}`.

You should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
@foreach($first as $key => $value)

    <div>
        <h2>{{ $value['title'] }}</h2>

        @foreach($value['fields'] as $field)

            {{ $field }} <br>

        @endforeach
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Please view the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data) for more information

Comment: Thanks, I know about the brackets, and honest to god I've tried what you described here and I only got errors. But this somehow magically works. Haha thanks a lot, lots to learn for me :)